# Linking to kml/kmz files on Google Drive

Tags: google-maps, overlay, kml, google-drive-api, permalinks

I've saved kml and kmz files in a file cabinet in the old Google Sites.  I copy the permalink to these files and paste it into the search box on Google Maps to overlay the placemarks.

I've saved a test kml file in a folder on the new Google Drive, but I can't figure out how to get a permalink that I can paste in Google Maps.  I found this link https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26371/how-do-i-share-a-permalink-from-google-drive and used it to create this permalink https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9sBXp66G86xWmlRbkZiYlRNdmc/edit?usp=sharing
but Google Maps does not recognize it as a valid kml file.  Do I need to change the URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set your root folder to share in the public. Right click on the folder > Share > Public on the web
2. Upload .html file in the directory > Open it > Preview
3. That's the url of your html, and you can find out the path to the kmz file that you want.

For example, here is my html file

https://googledrive.com/host/0B1YPetHU8aMQMmtrcFB4eTMzd1E/kml_overlay.html

My KMZ file url would be

https://googledrive.com/host/0B1YPetHU8aMQMmtrcFB4eTMzd1E/kmz/river.kmz

If you would like to see the list of files, access the root level.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kiichi, you were a big help.  I found the actual URL by right-clicking on the individual file name, selecting Details, and then copying the URL that appears below HOSTING.

Answer (score 2):

1. First check if is KML file valid for Google maps API (try it open e.g. at web version of google drive - if is valid web browser shows google map with kml layer).
2. Stored file address must have this form: 
   https://docs.google.com/host............
   (You can find the link at web version of google drive at file details/hosting)
   Link, that have form: https://drive.google.com/file...... will not work.
   (You can find the link at web version of google drive at file sharing

OR shortly sayed. Link must have file name at the end!!

1. Working example can be downloeded from:
   developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Answer (score 0):

If it is in **kml** format with specific name rename with a suitable name after downloading it to your pc/laptop which should **not have special characters or spaces** in it. For eg. if the name is ' **walking 19 02 14.kml**' then rename it as *walking190214.kml*.  If it is kmz file (it is just like zip ) like *'walking 19 02 14.kmz'* then first extract the **'doc.kml'** file in it and rename the 'doc' with a name as described above.  If you feel difficulty in extracting kmz file rename the kmz extension with zip extension ie **abcd.kmz** should be renamed as **abcd.zip** , then extract with *winzip or winrar* etc. Next upload the kml file to your **'Google sites / Google pages** .Detailed  steps are described in the following link

https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/pagesforkml

https://support.google.com/earth/answer/173934?hl=en﻿

Answer (score 0):

Some of the functionality of Google Drive has changed recently with the new look Google Drive, so do this:

1. Download the KML data file you want to visualise from Open Street Map or your local Ordnance Survey site.
2. In a browser open “Google Drive” and click “New” (top left corner)
   Click on “More >” and then “Google Fusion Tables” (or click “connect more apps” if "Google Fusion Tables" is not already available.
3. Import the downloaded KML file.
4. If for some reason the map doesn't display ensure that the latitude/longitude columns were loaded correctly and if necessary tag them using the down arrow option in the header of the CSV table.