# Unable to import layer from Google Drive to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-drive-api, gis, google-maps-markers, kml

I'm able to import a KML/KMZ layer hosted on my local drive just fine into Google Maps.  No issues.  However, when I attempt to host the same layer on Google Drive and import from Google Drive, I get the following error:

```
The file contains invalid or unsupported data, or the file is too large to parse.
```

I also notice that the icon of the KML file on drive is not the standard Globe icon (it is a globe when placed on my local drive) - but rather, it looks like:

```
</>
```

What is happening here? I need to import from Google Drive so I'd like to figure this out.  This also begs the question: if I do end up just adding the data from my local drive, what happens if I remove the KML from my drive?  Is the data in Google Maps dependent upon it, or once the KML is added to Google Maps, does that KML now exist independently in the cloud?

Comment: Does this help? [Linking to kml/kmz files on Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928455/linking-to-kml-kmz-files-on-google-drive)

Comment: When you say "Google Maps", do you mean that you're trying to import it into MyMaps, load it via the Google Maps JS API, or something else?

Comment: Problem here too (amazing!) You can upload GPS Logger (android app) files to your 'cloud,' download them to laptop and upload to MyMaps, but cannot import directly from the cloud.  Other method that works is GPS Logger's email - download and upload to MyMaps.